# How does one move SQL Server error log files to a new location?

Tags: sql-server

The default SQL Server log directory is full on my C drive. How does one move the SQL Server error log default directory?

Answer (score 4):

In `SSMS` go to server properties and look for start up parameters. Right-click in object explorer, properties, then `advanced`.

The path is the "e" switch. Change and restart.

It can't be set in documented SQL commands :-)

Basically, it's in the registry as one of the parameters to the sqlservr.exe binary when run as a windows service

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a tool interface for this. The registry key depends on the SQL version and isntance name, eg. SQL 2008 Default instance is: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQLServer\Parameters`

Comment: Btw, the parameter is not passed to the binary from the Service Control Manager. SCM passes only the instance name via  `-sINSTANCENAME` and the SQL binary then reads the startup parameters from its own registry key for the instance name passed in from SCM sstart up params.

Comment: I seem to recall using SQL 2000 EM to view it, but it's been some time obviously. As for startup, I usually think more about when running command-line startup to run single user mode etc

Comment: Found it, is the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool that allows you to set the startup parameters w/o having to manually edit the registry.

Comment: SQL Server Configuration Manager versions and names:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-configuration-manager

Answer (score 4):

Use the `SQL Configuration Manager`.

Here are the steps to change the startup to use a different directory. Once done restart server:

[image]

Comment: The new folder needs to have the correct security so SQL server can access it.  Review the security settings on the old folder and make the new folder the same.  When it comes to adding groups or user names to the security of a folder in this case, you need to include object type "service accounts", from this location the local server,  then specify, for example, "NT Service\MSSQLSERVER".

Answer (score 2):

When you use SSMS and click on generate script it creates T-SQL like this

```
  USE [msdb]
    GO
    EXEC dbo.sp_set_sqlagent_properties @errorlog_file=N'C:MSSQL\Log\SQLAGENT.OUT'
    GO
```

I just verified that it works, just make sure that the folder exist otherwise agent won't start

you probably also need to run this first, probably the proc above is disabled (by default)

```
EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1

RECONFIGURE

EXEC master.dbo.sp_configure 'Agent XPs', 1

RECONFIGURE
```

Comment: This answer relates to the SQL *Agent* error logs, which are different to the SQL Server logs themselves. Agent error log location can be changed in SSMS GUI, but that's an answer to a different question.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best solution if you have made Typo when entering a new path. Can be confirmed with the registry setting: find

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).