# Error in output for sql server error logs

Tags: c++, visual-c++, registry

I am implementing program for finding sql server logs. from [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/varund/archive/2009/03/21/how-to-verify-path-for-sql-server-error-log-files.aspx) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2247969/how-do-i-move-sql-server-error-log-files-to-a-new-location)i get information that sql server error logs store at "Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\Parameters" this path.

i try to implement code with this path but it gives me error in output that "RegOpenKeyEx failed, error code 5"

here is my code what is wrong in it?

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
HKEY hKey;



LONG dwRegOPenKey = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQLServer\\Parameters"), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);
// ahiya DS-Client ni service malse  LONG dwRegOPenKey = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, _T("SYSTEM\\CurrentControlSet\\Services\\DS-Client\Parameters\\"), 0, KEY_READ, &hKey);


if(dwRegOPenKey == ERROR_SUCCESS){
    printf("RegOpenKeyEx succeeded, error code %d\n", GetLastError());
    QueryKey(hKey);

    } else {
        printf("RegOpenKeyEx failed, error code %d\n", dwRegOPenKey);
    }


    RegCloseKey(hKey);
    system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: which version of VS you are using and which platform you are working. Also please check do you have proper admin rights or not. Try to 'Run as administrator'

Comment: hi i am using VS2010, if i write path for "Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQLServer" its working fine it also give output but when i try "Software\\Microsoft\\Microsoft SQL Server\\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\\MSSQLServer\\Parameters" in output it gives me error

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an 'Access Denied' error.

Using regedit, take a look at the permissions for the "**Software\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQLServer\Parameters**" key. On my system, you need Administrator rights for the 'Parameters' key as 'Users' does not have permission to view the key, however 'Users' does have permission to view the parent MSSQLSERVER key.

I would suggest therefore that this is the installation default.

You will need to run with administrator rights to view the parameters.

Comment: thank you very much its running though i cant get what i want..:(